How to run/trigger a Business Process (BP) whenever a file arrives from AS2 in IBM Sterling Integrator?
I am working on a recently installed Sterling Integrator and want to run a business process only when a file arrives from one of my AS2 partner.
In the BP that I want to run, it uses CLA2 to run a script which is responsible to move the file after changing the extension of the file.
Please help as I am not finding a way to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried using FSA but not able to achieve this requirement.
I have also tried to configure the AS2 relationship to run a BP but that didn't workout as well as I am not sure of the further steps.

I usually drop the data into a folder and then run a FSA every 15 minutes to pick up the data and do something with it.  But if you need it more real time you can have the data drop into a mailbox and run a routing rule to kick off a BP.
